# How to write a custom ValidationRule

Tags: aurelia

The intro for the aurelia-validation plugin contains a section on creating custom ValidationRules, by  extending the ValidationRule class and passing it to the passes function. The example given is as follows:

```
import {ValidationRule} from './plugins/validation/';
export class MyValidationRule extends ValidationRule{
constructor (isValid) {
    super(
        isValid, //pass any object as 'threshold'
        (newValue, threshold) => { //pass a validation function
             return threshold;
        }
        (newValue, threshold) => { //Optionally pass a function that will provide an error message
            return `needs to be at least ${threshold} characters long`;
        },
    );
}
}
```

What do I do with this? For example, for demo purposes if i wanted to make a function that checks if the value is a phone number with regex, how would i code that using this template? I'm asking because the documentation is sparse with examples; there are none for writing custom validation rules and the other example shows how to add one to the ValidationGroup prototype but I would like to know both methods of adding a custom rule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't have to create a custom validation rule class. You may just make a function which accepts an argument and returns the validation result, e.g.

```
function validatePhoneNumber(newValue) {
    return true/*your RegExp check should return true/false here*/;
}
```

and then

```
this.validation = validation.on(this)
                            .passes(validatePhoneNumber);
```

If you think you need a class to make validation more generic, try something like

```
import {ValidationRule} from './plugins/validation/';
export class RegExpValidationRule extends ValidationRule {
    constructor (regExp, errorMessage) {
        super(
            regExp, 
            (newValue, threshold) => { 
                return true/*your RegExp check should return true/false here*/;
            },
            (newValue, threshold) => { 
                return errorMessage;
            }
        );
    }
}
```

and then

```
var validationRule = new RegExpValidationRule(/*your RegExp*/, 'Invalid phone number');
this.validation = validation.on(this)
                            .passesRule(validationRule);
```

Comment: This may be what i'm looking for. A stupid question but would i need to import the custom rule into the calling class as well for this to hook up correctly?

Comment: Yes, just import {RegExpValidationRule} from 'yourfile';

Comment: I now get the following console error:
`Unhandled promise rejection Error: Unexpected behavior: a validation-rules-collection should always fulfil`
` at Error (native)
    at http://10.172.102.162:9000/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-validation@0.6.0/validation-property.js:79:19
    at h (http://10.172.102.162:9000/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@1.2.6/client/shim.min.js:1773:66)
    at http://10.172.102.162:9000/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@1.2.6/client/shim.min.js:1778:19
    at MutationObserver.e (http://10.172.102.162:9000/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@1.2.6/client/shim.min.js:1958:55)`

Comment: also in your top example, the validatePhoneNumber function takes a newValue parameter, but when you call it no value is passed in, is this intentional?

Comment: I don't call this function, I pass a reference to it to be called by aurelia. So it's intentional.

Comment: I changed my answer to fix several errors there... now it works fine for me